# Read XML from URL and bind to Listbox in WP7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 which read a **XML file**, take some elements and bind them to a `listbox`
Here is the code:

```
XDocument data = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

var persons = from query in data.Descendants("Table")
select new Person
{
Phone = (string)query.Element("Phone"),
Name= (string)query.Element("Name"),
};

listBox1.ItemsSource = persons;

public class Person
{
string Phone;
string Name;

public string Phone
{
 get { return phone; }
 set { phone = value; }
}

public string ame
{
get { return name; }
set { name = value; }
```

Now i want to do the same but the XML file is on a URL.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `WebClient` class to get the content from URL and then parse it to `XDocument` object:

- [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
- [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx)

You can try something like that:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpCompleted;
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://domain/path/file.xml"));
```

and the HttpCompeted:

```
private void HttpCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

        // do something with the XDocument here
    }
}
```